# Django, ngnix, and uwsgi site cannot deploy on remote server

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I need to deploy my django site using ngnix and uwsgi. it works fine in localhost. but when I give my remote server, it does not work. this is my ngnix.conf file

```
# nginx.conf
   upstream django {
       # connect to this socket
       server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;        # for a file socket
       #server 127.0.0.1:8001;        # for a web port socket
       }

   server {
       # the port your site will be served on
       listen      80;
       # the domain name it will serve for
       server_name 192.168.101.191;        # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
       charset     utf-8;

       #Max upload size
       client_max_body_size 75M;        # adjust to taste

       # Django media
       location /media  {
                   alias /home/calcey/django_env_2/employee/media;        # your Django project's media files
       }

           location /static {
                   alias /home/calcey/django_env_2/employee/static;        # your Django project's static files
           }

       # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
       location / {
           uwsgi_pass  django;
           include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # or the uwsgi_params you installed manually
           }



       }
```

"192.168.101.191" means my server IP address. if I put local host instead of "192.168.101.191" it works. but for remote IP it does not work. please give me a suggestion.

Comment: what does "it does not work" mean? Have you seen the logs? Try to explain the problem with more detail please.

Answer (score 0):

Your server IP address looks some kind of `Internal IP`. But anyway, you do Not need any Server IP address as long as your `Nginx` script is running on the Server.

You can use the following configurations Instead:

```
Server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 127.0.0.1;
   ....
   ....
   ....
}
```

Hopefully, this will solve your problem.